# Why is a google.script.run call being repeated?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am calling a function on the server that adds a few hundred objects to the ScriptDB database from the client using google.script.run. However, I have found that the server function is called more than once so the database ends up with duplicates of these objects.

```
function serverFunction(bigarray) {
  // This function is called multiple times
  db.saveBatch(bigarray);
}
```

Yet I can verify that the code on the client that calls `serverFunction` is only run once.

```
function clientFunction() {
  alert("This function is only called once.");
  google.script.run.serverFunction(bigarray);
}
```

1. Could my server code be timing out and getting run again automatically by GAS?
2. If so, how long is the time out and is this functionality documented anywhere?
3. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its currently 30 seconds. This is a known issue and will be fixed fairly soon. (Its not a regression per se since its been like this since day 1 but I need to fix it to match the scripts own five minute timeout).

Comment: Thanks! Is there already an issue in the tracker that I can follow?